# Pushing an array into empty array in loop

Tags: javascript

I am pushing a vector into array in the loop.
Here is a code snippet

```
    var atoms = [];
    for (var i=0; i<formulas.length; i++) {
        for (var atom in formulas[i].data.atoms) {
            if (atoms.indexOf(atom) < 0) {
                atoms.push(atom);
            }
        }
    }
var zeroMatrix = [];
for (var i=0; i<formulas.length; i++) {
    var vector = atoms.map(function(item) {return formulas[i].data.atoms.hasOwnProperty(item) ? formulas[i].data.atoms[item] : 0});
    vector.push(0);
    console.log(vector);
    console.log(zeroMatrix);
    zeroMatrix.push(vector);
    console.log(zeroMatrix);
}
```

Results printed into the console are as follows

1) `[1,2,0,0] // vector`

2) `[] // zeroMatrix`

and now surprise

3) `[[1,2,1,0],[2,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0]] // zeroMatrix after pushing the vector`

Moreover, it pushes as expected if I run this in debug.
Do you have any idea what can cause this behavior?

Comment: Please show the actual loop.

Comment: @RichardKho here you are. If you need any other info just let mi know. Thanks.

Comment: What does you `formulas` array look like

Comment: @JacobCarter it is an object of this structure {formula : 'FeS2', {data : {atoms : {Fe : 1, S : 2}} , molecularWeight : 123}}

Comment: and the `atoms` array you are referencing when you call `atoms.map()`

Comment: Fairly certain there's an issue here not represented in the code you shared. This works as expected with dummy data in your format.

Comment: You obviously messed up `[]` and `{}`. On object `{formula : 'FeS2', {data : {atoms : {Fe : 1, S : 2}} , molecularWeight : 123}}` can't be iterated in an Array manner using `for(var i=0...` and indexing `[i]`

Comment: @nrabinowitz I am sure there is some bug in my code. However it seems to me really weird that it works perfectly in debug while I obtain this weird array when run normally.

Comment: @KirillSlatin actually the structure is right. The formula is an object ... formulas is an array of these objects

Comment: @nrabinowitz What I have showed is the whole body of given function. There is nothing more happening before (formulas are passed as parameter)

Comment: It happened to me that console.log would not reflect true state of objects sometimes. Or at least not at the precise moment the `console.log` was made.

Comment: Sorry about the closure answer it should not be your issue. The console thing happens to me not very often, but I learned my lesson and stopped trusting it a while ago.

Comment: The issue seems fixed, but try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4060176/1291428

Comment: @Sebas No problem, it was rather possible origin of this issue. I do not use JS very much so I still need to learn through mistakes like this. OK, lesson learnt ... do not trust the console :)

Comment: The other thing: did you try in different browsers?

Comment: @Sebas I did now. It prints out [[1,2,1,0]] in internet explorer. In my opinion , there is a problem with an inner state of computation.

Comment: Try with `console.log(JSON.stringify(zeroMatrix))`

Comment: @Sebas stringified object printed as expected ... doh. I have just spent 2 hours on fixing something what actually had worked :) Thank you for your time and very good inputs.